# preparing an input table on google tag manager server side to be send as part of an API request body

Tags: javascript, api, google-tag-manager, hubspot

I am using Google Tag Manager Server Container.

I am trying to make a POST API call to

```
https://api.hubapi.com/events/v3/send?hapikey={{hubspot api key}}
```

The parts in between {{ }} are variables taken and set within google tag manager. They are populating properly.

The purpose of this API call is to send a custom behaviour event (similar to google analytics event) to Hubspot - [custom behaviour events manual tracking](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/analytics/events)

For these events, you can send in properties like page url, google cid, file type, page title etc.

These properties are added to the request body, so they are included in the **setBody** in the following request

```
sendHttpRequest(url, (statusCode, headers, body) => {
                if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode <300) {
                  data.gtmOnSuccess();
                } else {
                 data.gtmOnFailure();
            }
              setResponseStatus(statusCode);
              setResponseHeader('cache-control', headers['cache-control']);
              setResponseBody(body);
},{headers: postHeaders, method: 'POST', timeout: 3000}, setBody);
```

**setBody** is set with the following code:

```
if (data.additionalProperties) {
  for (let key in data.additionalProperties) {
    postPropertiesData = ["{",postPropertiesData, data.additionalProperties[key].property,":",data.additionalProperties[key].value,"}"].join('');
  }
}


const postProperties = JSON.stringify(postPropertiesData);

const setProperties = JSON.stringify({
  utk: data.userToken,
  eventName: data.eventName,
  ocurredAt: getTimestamp(),
});

const setBody = [setProperties,'properties:',postProperties].join(' ');
```

the `(if (data.additionalProperties)` section takes the properties from an input table like this
[image: input table in gtm server side].

**data.additionalProperties** access the table. The left column has the internal name called *property* and the right column has the internal name called *value*.

I need it to output as an object to 'properties': {'firstname':'michael','lastname':'stone','email':'michael.stone@gmail.com'} and then stringified using **JSON.stringify()** function

I used the code above to try prepare to be part of the request body.

I have also tried.

```
let postPropertiesData = {};

if (data.additionalProperties) {
  for (let key in data.additionalProperties) {
    postPropertiesData[data.additionalProperties[key].property =data.additionalProperties[key].value,"};
  }
}




const setBody = JSON.stringify({
  utk: data.userToken,
  eventName: data.eventName,
  properties: postPropertiesData,
  ocurredAt: getTimestamp(),
});
```

either way I get the same result

the properties part is empty.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end, I found the answer. I had to use the makeTableMap API

so I did `const makeTableMap = require('makeTableMap');`

and then instead of the if statements and the for, I used a ternary within the object itself.

```
const setBody = JSON.stringify({
  'portalId':data.portalID,
  'utk': data.userToken,
  'eventName': data.eventName,
  'properties': (data.additionalProperties) ? makeTableMap(data.additionalProperties,'property','value'):{},
  'ocurredAt': getTimestamp(),
});
```

and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the source of this HubSpot GTM Server Side tag https://github.com/stape-io/hubspot-tag

It also has functionality to send custom behaviour events to HubSpot.

And a blog post about how to use it is here https://stape.io/how-to-connect-website-with-hubspot-using-server-side-tracking/

Comment: I see that you uploaded that to github. It's nice, but it's limited. For example, my end goal is to be able to use the hubspot user token to get the id so I can make an update. I don't have their email address and sending that through the google tag manager web version risks exposing PII,

Comment: we use it like this:
- user submit registration form. 
- we have user email at this moment and send it to the GTM Server.
- on GTM we send users emails to few systems one of them is HubSpot.

It's normal to send a user email on registration. That is what backend developers usually do.

Comment: Also, HubSpot Stape tag supports "utk" in case you don't have email but have stored utk in cookies.